# How to either restart the Javascript or combine onclick mouseenter mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my JS that works only on the first time around (need to refresh for it to work again)

```
  $('.example-form').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('myClickState');
      });

   $('.example-form').on('mouseenter', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('myClickState');
      });

   $('.example-form').on('mouseleave', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $( this ).css("border-color","rgba(0, 0, 0, .075)");
      });
```

Here's code that works for the hover action, but i can't seem to add the click function correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( ".example-form" )
  .mouseenter(function() {
  $( this ).css("border","red solid 1px");
  })
      .mouseleave(function() {
  $( this ).css("border-color","rgba(0, 0, 0, .075)");
  });
});
```

How can I add the onclick function so it works with the latter code?

I'm looking to have the search form box when clicked, border turns red, when clicked outside the search box, goes away.  When hovered, border turns read.

Comment: Your first code work http://jsfiddle.net/4dc2wmsb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window)
       .click(function() {
        $( ".example-form" ).css("border","rgba(0, 0, 0, .075) solid 1px");
    });

    $('.example-form')
        .click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            $( this ).css("border","red solid 1px");
        })
        .mouseenter(function() {
            $( this ).css("border","red solid 1px");
        });
});
```

but you must know, that Using stopEventPropagation() is something that should be avoided as it breaks normal event flow in the DOM.

another variant is in using .focusout()

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.example-form')
        .focusout(function(){
            $( this ).css("border","rgba(0, 0, 0, .075) solid 1px");
        })
        .click(function(){
            $( this ).css("border","red solid 1px");
        })
        .mouseenter(function() {
            $( this ).css("border","red solid 1px");
        });
});
```

You can read about it here http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: This is close.  I added mouseleave under mouseenter so it doesn't stay red if i just hover over it.  but the only issue is that when i click and leave, the function goes away.  in what way can i make it so something like "mouseleave only if mouseenter is triggered"?

Comment: than you need to add - remove classes: `$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.example-form')
            .focusout(function(){
                $( this ).removeClass('inputactive');
            })
            .click(function(){
                $( this ).addClass('inputactive');
            })
            .mouseenter(function() {
                $( this ).addClass('mouseover');

            })
            .mouseleave(function(){
                $( this ).removeClass('mouseover');
            });
    });`

and css:
`.mouseover, .inputactive {border: red solid 1px;}`

Comment: that works! thank you.  I'm going to "check" you right now.. but... how do i remove that 'flicker' that happens when i hover over it?.. the entire page shifts when i hover over the search...

Comment: that's because of CSS - you must add `input {border: 1px solid grey;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on` and specify multiple events and separate them with space.

```js
$('.example-form').on('click mouseenter', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).css("border","red solid 1px");
}).on('mouseleave', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).css("border-color","rgba(0, 0, 0, .075)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="submit" class="example-form">
  <input type="search" />
</form>
```